# Input for a Surface/XNA Application

Tags: c#, xna, windows-store-apps

I'm new to Microsoft Surface Application development, and I'd like to know how I would go about handling touch events and user input in a way that I can test it on the Surface using touch input and in the simulator using mouse input. Basically, I want to make a simple game kinda like Pong where you have to drag a "paddle" and block a moving projectile; simple drag and drop movement, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PreviewTouchDown`,`PreviewTouchUp`,`PreviewTouchMove`-events. Every touch gets it's own unique ID. It can be very useful when you need to check & save `TouchPoints` for your gestures.

I attach those events to my Root Grid.